# ValueGetters in ag-grid, not filtering as expected

Tags: angular, ag-grid

I have a valueGetter defined on one of the grid's column and based on the value received, I am changing the values to 2.0 ,2.1 etc.
The floating filer component is working fine for values 2.1,2.2 etc but when I am trying to filter value for 2.0 its not functioning.

```
if (field === "name") {
            let updatedValue;
            def["valueGetter"] = function (params) {
               
                if(params.node.data.ver == "2.1" && params.node.data.name) {
                   updatedValue = "2.0";
                }
                else {
                    updatedValue = params.node.data.ver
                }
                return updatedValue;
            }
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem when value is 2.0? Error or what

Comment: the problem is when I try to filter by entering 2.0 in the floating filter,it doesnt filter in grid.But when the value entered is 2,1,then it is filtering in the grid.

Comment: see if you can recreate it in jsfiddle or plunker. It would be helpful for us in solving this